# Reading multiple strings in Arduino

Tags: c, serial-port, arduino

I am basically trying to read a string through the serial port. I have used "Serial.readstringUntil" syntax to read a string and then compare to some data. I am successfully able to do that. Now in the same program I want to read another string again and then compare it with some other data. But it fails since the comparison is done between the previously loaded string. What can be the issue. Not a pro! Sorry. 
Here is the code.

```
int x;
String str;
String data="on";
String data2="off";
void calfunc();
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  Serial.println("Enter");


}
void loop() 
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    str = Serial.readStringUntil(' ');
    //x = Serial.parseInt();
    //Serial.println(str);
    if(str.equals (data))
    {
      Serial.println("Access Granted. ");
      calfunc();
    }
    else if(str.equals(data2))
    {
      digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      Serial.println("Access Denied");
    }
  }
  delay(100);
}

void calfunc(){
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);


  Serial.println("For Temperature press 1");
  Serial.println("For Moisture press 2");
  delay(100);

  char a=Serial.read();
  if(a=='1')
  {
    Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
  }
  else if(a=='2')
  {
    Serial.println(analogRead(A1));
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Wrong Choice");
    delay(500);
    return;
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `SPACE` as your termination char?

Answer (score 0):

hi I noticed that you have used the C "else if" statements in your loop() function however you have not finished with an else statement

```
if(boolean_expression 1)
{
   /* Executes when the boolean expression 1 is true */
}
else if( boolean_expression 2)
{
   /* Executes when the boolean expression 2 is true */
}
else if( boolean_expression 3)
{
   /* Executes when the boolean expression 3 is true */
}
else 
{
   /* executes when the none of the above condition is true */
}
```

can you please try this, I do not have Arduino compiler installed

```
void loop() 
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    str = Serial.readStringUntil(' ');
    //x = Serial.parseInt();
    //Serial.println(str);
    if(str.equals (data))
    {
      Serial.println("Access Granted. ");
      calfunc();
    }

    if(str.equals(data2))
    {
      digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      Serial.println("Access Denied");
    }
  }
  delay(100);
}
```